Made a mistake on job application and got the job offer
Edit: The application had my resume attached, which has no mistakes and is 100% accurate. I also gave this exact resume in physical copies to HR during my first interview, although they said they have my information already.
I applied to a job and had Indeed automatically complete my resume/job application based on my listed work experience. I have passed the interviews, and signed the offer, and is now in the process of filling out the background check information. As I was double-checking what I filled on the background check forms against the job application, I realized I made a big mistake.
The job application that's generated by Indeed put the wrong employer name, and location. I have 3 experiences listed on the application all different companies, and different roles, but now 2 of them are listed under the same company.
What should I do? Should I notify the recruiter? Or should I just keep quiet and put the right company name in the background check form? I really don't want to lose my first job after graduation.

What would you normally do when you make a mistake? Bring it to the attention of the relevant parties so that it can be corrected. That's what you should do.

@joeqwerty please don't answer in comments :) post an answer instead

@DarkCygnus you know that if Joe posted that as an answer you would fault him for it being too short, lacking detail etc etc

@SolarMike not necesarilly, an answer may be short and to the point and still be of quality. Naturally, just posting a one-liner may not be the best move, and enhancing a bit would be necessary. Regardless, answering in comments is not encouraged, and I never said "post exactly that as an answer"; merely reminded politely that answering in comments is not encouraged and suggesting Joe that their comment is answer-material. "I" would never "fault" anybody :) I would just leave feedback/suggestions


Should I notify the recruiter?

Yes. ASAP.
If the recruiter does not respond, then talk to HR or the hiring manager ASAP.
If you talk to them ASAP, I don't think this will hurt your chance of getting the jobs. You only mess up a few small details on either your resume or application form. They will understand if you try to clarify these details.
